# No checking condition in for loop C++

Tags: c++

```
char i;

for (i = 1; i < 10, i++;) 
{
    cout << (i+1) << endl;
}

return 0;
```

I understand that for loop has the following syntax:

```
for(initialization; condition; increment)
{

}
```

As I run the debug, why it never checks the condition and it eventually stops at i = 0?

(Thank you Damien and Andars, I don't know why the "on purpose" statement was removed, but you interpret my question correctly. Could someone explain why the complier skips the condition before the comma, and why the loop stop at i = 0 instead of looping forever? Thanks!)

Comment: It's the comma operator.

Comment: Like @chris said, you need a semi-colon after the ten and before the i.

Comment: As @chris indicates, change the comma after the 10 to a semicolon.  And you can remove the semicolon before the closing parenthesis too.  Finally, you would normally declare `i` as type `int` not `char`.

Comment: Use herohuyongtao's answer, but use `int i = 1;` instead of `i = 1;`.  Also, remove the `char i;` statement.

Comment: I find it strange that `i < 10, i++` even compiles without an error (according to OP's description). But assuming it does indeed compile without an error, how would you explain the behavior OP is describing? The condition `i < 10, i++` should be true for at least 10 iterations (or possibly forever, depending on how the compiler interpreted the comma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe he is indicating that he wrote the code that way on purpose.

To answer, i++ will always return true. The last value is the value that matters with comma separated statements, so the loop will not stop.

Edit for elaborations:

It isn't simply using a logical or, it disregards what is before the comma and only takes the last value. The value of anything non-zero is considered true, and since i starts at 1, and goes up, it will always be non-zero (until it overflows and wraps back around, which explains why i ends at 0).

If you say:

```
x = 4, 5, 6;
```

x will be equal to 6, the last value.

Comment: This answers my comment above. So the compiler took the comma for a logical-or?

Comment: No, not an or, it disregards what is before the comma and only takes the last value. The value of anything non-zero is considered true, and since i starts at 1, and goes up, it will always be non-zero.

Comment: _goes up, it will always be non-zero._ I disagree! it showed me Zero as well!

Comment: it is overflowing, maybe

Comment: Got it. Seems like you're the only one to understand his "wrote this on purpose" statement (which has now been removed for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (i = 1; i < 10, i++;)
```

to

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) //Notice correct placement of ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me also that the code was written incorrectly on purpose. As others have mentioned, the comma operator will discard the value of the `i<10` and only `i++` will be evaluated as condition. This will return true until `i` overflows (values only from -127 to 127) and ends up at `-1`, when `i++` will return 0 and the loop exits. Thus the final value for i will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used the comma operator instead of a semi-colon